# Basic doubt on Stirling numbers of Second Type

Tags: combinatorics

When learning Stirling numbers of Second Type, one simple doubt came to my mind and posting it here.

The formula for Stirling numbers of Second Type is given as
$S(n,k)=\dfrac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^k(-1)^j.^kC_j.(k-j)^n$

But when $j=k, (k-j)^k = 0$. Hence, the formula can be

$S(n,k)=\dfrac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j.^kC_j.(k-j)^n$

Why it is always represented in the first way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two reasons. First, the usual way avoids any question about the meaning of $\sum_{j=0}^{-1}$. Second, and more important, $(k-j)^n$ is *not* $0$ when $j=k=n=0$: it’s $1$.

Comment: sorry, still getting doubt on the point. when k=j, it will be 0^n which is 0 right?

Comment: ah, got your point, the first one is an expression which takes care of the special cases also. right?

Comment: @Kiran: $0^n=0$ if $n>0$, but $0^0=1$, and you need that, since $S(0,0)=1$.

Comment: @Kiran: You’re welcome.